# Erro ao Mapear IDataReader com AutoMapper

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, automapper

Estou com esse erro de tipagem ao tentar mapear um SqlDataReader vindo de uma procedure, mapeando com o AutoMapper

***Erro***

> An unhandled exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException'
>   occurred in AutoMapper.dll
>
> Additional information: Error mapping types

***Segue meu DataReader***

```
public List<T> DataReader<T>(string Procedure, List<SqlParameter> parameters)
{
    var rows = ExecuteProcedureReader(Procedure, parameters);

    if (rows.HasRows)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { });
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        return mapper.Map<IDataReader, List<T>>(rows);
    }

    return null;
}
```

***Minha Classe***

```
public class Usuario
{
    public int Codigo { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public string Emdereco { get; set; }

    public string Cpf { get; set; }
}
```

***Chamada do meu método***

```
var lista = conn.DataReader<Usuario>("PR_USUARIO_CONSULTAR", param);

foreach (var item in lista)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Nome);
}
```

Comment: Onde está e como está sendo feita a inicialização do AutoMapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema foi resolvido configurando o AutoMapper para que ele mapeie dinamicamente o objeto, através do `CreateMissingTypeMaps`.

Segue o Código:

```
public List<T> DataReader<T>(string Procedure, List<SqlParameter> parameters)
{
    var rows = ExecuteProcedureReader(Procedure, parameters);

    if (rows.HasRows)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true; });
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        return mapper.Map<IDataReader, List<T>>(rows);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Por que você não cria o mapeamento em vez de fazer isso aí? `Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, List<UmTipoQueVocêUsa>>();`?